# Deploying Flask App on Heroku

Tags: heroku, flask

I apologize in advance if it is a massive mistake. I created Flaskr, the Flask tutorial App http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/packaging/#tutorial-packaging, on the local server it works fine but when I try to deploy the app on Heroku, Heroku responds "Application error".
I am using the same file structure of the tutorial i just added a Procfile in the root of my app. The Procfile contains the following lines:

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=true
flask run
```

Logs give no errors, dyno is running fine, but the app is not running. Any suggestion? Is Heroku even the best way to deploy this app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) is used to start application or execute other command, you have to declare a `web` process to start Heroku server, it should like this:

```
web: gunicorn -k gevent app:app
```

Or without `gevent`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

You can also add gunicorn option:

```
web: gunicorn -w 4 app:app
```

Also, `gunicorn` and `gevent(optional)` should be included in your `requirements.txt` file.

In the code above, the first `app` is python file's name (i.e.`app.py`), the second is the application instance's name (i.e.`app = Flask(__name__)`).

Here is a Flask application template for heroku: https://github.com/zachwill/flask_heroku